# How can I get the attribute set collection using ObjectManager in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes

How can I get the attribute set collection using the `ObjectManager`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory` like this:

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$attributeSetCollectionFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\CollectionFactory');
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\Collection $attributeSetCollection */
$attributeSetCollection = $attributeSetCollectionFactory->create();
$attributeSets = $attributeSetCollection->getItems();
/** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set $attributeSet */
foreach ($attributeSets as $attributeSet) {
    echo $attributeSet->getAttributeSetName() . chr(10) . chr(13);
}
```

Result (on my test host):

[image: result]